# My Android app crashes with "Found invalid root: 0x2"

Tags: java, android, crash, garbage-collection

I need some help interpreting a stack trace!

I am writing an OpenGL game for Android, and I am almost done.  I *just* updated to Android 5.1.1 on a Nexus 5.
The app uses the bullet physics library, as built by LibGDX, which is native code.

After updating, my app has started crashing intermittently.
Here is the top of the crash stack:

```
09-06 23:34:23.664: E/art(1778): Tried to mark 0x2 not contained by any spaces
09-06 23:34:23.664: E/art(1778): Attempting see if it's a bad root
09-06 23:34:23.666: E/art(1778): Found invalid root: 0x2 
09-06 23:34:23.666: E/art(1778): Type=RootJavaFrame thread_id=14 location=Visiting method 'com.spher.cblast.world.Signal com.spher.cblast.activities.BulletLevelScene.updateBoard(float)' at dex PC 0x01a8 (native PC 0xa392ace3) vreg=9
09-06 23:34:23.666: A/art(1778): art/runtime/gc/collector/mark_sweep.cc:381] Can't mark invalid object
09-06 23:34:23.904: A/art(1778): art/runtime/runtime.cc:289] Runtime aborting...
09-06 23:34:23.904: A/art(1778): art/runtime/runtime.cc:289] Aborting thread:
09-06 23:34:23.904: A/art(1778): art/runtime/runtime.cc:289] "GLThread 972" prio=5 tid=14 Runnable
09-06 23:34:23.904: A/art(1778): art/runtime/runtime.cc:289]   | group="" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x12c22bc0 self=0xb4a26c00
09-06 23:34:23.904: A/art(1778): art/runtime/runtime.cc:289]   | sysTid=1812 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0xb491b280
09-06 23:34:23.904: A/art(1778): art/runtime/runtime.cc:289]   | state=R schedstat=( 28691639167 2902450009 24576 ) utm=2811 stm=58 core=0 HZ=100
09-06 23:34:23.904: A/art(1778): art/runtime/runtime.cc:289]   | stack=0xb353e000-0xb3540000 stackSize=1036KB
09-06 23:34:23.904: A/art(1778): art/runtime/runtime.cc:289]   | held mutexes= "abort lock" "mutator lock"(shared held)
09-06 23:34:23.904: A/art(1778): art/runtime/runtime.cc:289]   native: #00 pc 00004e64  /system/lib/libbacktrace_libc++.so (UnwindCurrent::Unwind(unsigned int, ucontext*)+23)
09-06 23:34:23.904: A/art(1778): art/runtime/runtime.cc:289]   native: #01 pc 00003665  /system/lib/libbacktrace_libc++.so (Backtrace::Unwind(unsigned int, ucontext*)+8)
09-06 23:34:23.904: A/art(1778): art/runtime/runtime.cc:289]   native: #02 pc 00256429  /system/lib/libart.so (art::DumpNativeStack(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, int, char const*, art::mirror::ArtMethod*)+84)
09-06 23:34:23.904: A/art(1778): art/runtime/runtime.cc:289]   native: #03 pc 00238fe7  /system/lib/libart.so (art::Thread::Dump(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&) const+158)
09-06 23:34:23.904: A/art(1778): art/runtime/runtime.cc:289]   native: #04 pc 0022881d  /system/lib/libart.so (art::AbortState::DumpThread(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, art::Thread*)+32)
09-06 23:34:23.904: A/art(1778): art/runtime/runtime.cc:289]   native: #05 pc 00228a87  /system/lib/libart.so (art::AbortState::Dump(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&)+354)
09-06 23:34:23.904: A/art(1778): art/runtime/runtime.cc:289]   native: #06 pc 00228c7f  /system/lib/libart.so (art::Runtime::Abort()+82)
09-06 23:34:23.904: A/art(1778): art/runtime/runtime.cc:289]   native: #07 pc 000a7371  /system/lib/libart.so (art::LogMessage::~LogMessage()+1360)
09-06 23:34:23.904: A/art(1778): art/runtime/runtime.cc:289]   native: #08 pc 0012d81b  /system/lib/libart.so (bool art::gc::accounting::HeapBitmap::AtomicTestAndSet<art::gc::collector::MarkSweepMarkObjectSlowPath>(art::mirror::Object const*, art::gc::collector::MarkSweepMarkObjectSlowPath const&)+442)
09-06 23:34:23.904: A/art(1778): art/runtime/runtime.cc:289]   native: #09 pc 0012d8ef  /system/lib/libart.so (art::gc::collector::MarkSweep::MarkObjectParallel(art::mirror::Object const*)+142)
09-06 23:34:23.904: A/art(1778): art/runtime/runtime.cc:289]   native: #10 pc 0012eaeb  /system/lib/libart.so (art::gc::collector::MarkSweep::MarkRootParallelCallback(art::mirror::Object**, void*, art::RootInfo const&)+26)
09-06 23:34:23.904: A/art(1778): art/runtime/runtime.cc:289]   native: #11 pc 0023d86f  /system/lib/libart.so (art::ReferenceMapVisitor<art::RootCallbackVisitor>::VisitQuickFrame()+806)
09-06 23:34:23.905: A/art(1778): art/runtime/runtime.cc:289]   native: #12 pc 0023dcb9  /system/lib/libart.so (art::ReferenceMapVisitor<art::RootCallbackVisitor>::VisitFrame()+224)
09-06 23:34:23.905: A/art(1778): art/runtime/runtime.cc:289]   native: #13 pc 00231959  /system/lib/libart.so (art::StackVisitor::WalkStack(bool)+276)
09-06 23:34:23.905: A/art(1778): art/runtime/runtime.cc:289]   native: #14 pc 002336b3  /system/lib/libart.so (art::Thread::VisitRoots(void (*)(art::mirror::Object**, void*, art::RootInfo const&), void*)+994)
09-06 23:34:23.905: A/art(1778): art/runtime/runtime.cc:289]   native: #15 pc 0012db67  /system/lib/libart.so (art::gc::collector::CheckpointMarkThreadRoots::Run(art::Thread*)+126)
09-06 23:34:23.905: A/art(1778): art/runtime/runtime.cc:289]   native: #16 pc 00233c2f  /system/lib/libart.so (art::Thread::RunCheckpointFunction()+182)
09-06 23:34:23.905: A/art(1778): art/runtime/runtime.cc:289]   native: #17 pc 0008774f  /system/lib/libart.so (art::JniMethodStart(art::Thread*)+390)
09-06 23:34:23.905: A/art(1778): art/runtime/runtime.cc:289]   native: #18 pc 000c5de3  /data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@com.sphericalsoft.cannonblast-2@base.apk@classes.dex (Java_com_badlogic_gdx_physics_bullet_dynamics_DynamicsJNI_btDiscreteDynamicsWorld_1stepSimulation_1_1SWIG_11__JLcom_badlogic_gdx_physics_bullet_dynamics_btDiscreteDynamicsWorld_2FI+78)
09-06 23:34:23.905: A/art(1778): art/runtime/runtime.cc:289]   at com.badlogic.gdx.physics.bullet.dynamics.DynamicsJNI.btDiscreteDynamicsWorld_stepSimulation__SWIG_1(Native method)
09-06 23:34:23.905: A/art(1778): art/runtime/runtime.cc:289]   at com.badlogic.gdx.physics.bullet.dynamics.btDiscreteDynamicsWorld.stepSimulation(btDiscreteDynamicsWorld.java:71)
09-06 23:34:23.905: A/art(1778): art/runtime/runtime.cc:289]   at com.spher.cblast.activities.BulletLevelScene.updateBoard(BulletLevelScene.java:1010)
```

I am calling the native bullet 'stepSimulation' method.
Somehow, the garbage collector appears to be finding an invalid root, whatever that means.  The stack trace is always the same.

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: are you doing xml parsing? if yes post ur code

Comment: Hi, no I am not doing XML parsing.  I have loaded 3D models into bullet, and am updating the scene according to the physics world.  It works great most of the time :-(

Comment: this error is generally comes because of an invalid character string in your data stream.

Comment: An invalid character in an XML stream generally causes a XMLStreamError exception (or similar) to be thrown.  I am getting a crash with:  A/libc(1778): Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 1812 (GLThread 972)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I have eliminated my crash.

My call flow went from:

updateBoard(Java) --> Bullet::stepSimulation(native) --> collisionCallback(Java)

Inside the Java collisionCallback, I was dereferencing some objects, causing garbage.

I modified the code to no longer discard the objects in the collisionCallback, and I have not seen the crash since.